# Does Drupal.t() inside JS file has the same restrictions as the PHP t()?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have read that the string parameter passed to t() function should be literal, which excludes:

- variables, even the parameters of a function: `t($description)`
- a concatenation of strings: `t('If you want to add a link, click on' . '<a href="http://example.com">this link</a>.')`
- the value returned from a function:`t(get_menu_description())`
- a constant: `t(MYMODULE_MY_WIDGET_TITLE)`, `t(MyClass::WIDGET_TITLE)`

as mentioned here [Is it always bad to pass a variable through t()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/is-it-always-bad-to-pass-a-variable-through-t).

So, does Drupal.t() inside JS file has the same restrictions? as I have find a string inside some module that is passed as a variable

```
 $(this).addClass('open').text(Drupal.t(settings.linkText));
```

This string `settings.linkText` can't be located at the translation interface and I tried to change it to

```
 $(this).addClass('open').text(Drupal.t('@txt',{@txt:settings.linkText}));
```

but still couldn't find it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The string will show up in the translation interface if it is found by the js code parser. And a variable can't be worked on by the parser, it has to be a string. So

```
$(this).addClass('open').text(Drupal.t(settings.linkText));
```

can't show up. 
It doesn't prevent the string to be translated though, if the js is aware by another way of the translation : if you write somewhere else in your js

```
Drupal.t('my_string');
```

then the parser will find 'my_string' to translate, and the js will load it next time it's called, and if `settings.linkText` happens to equals `'my_string'`, then it will be translated.

You have to flush the js cache after the js code alteration, so the parser can look again for strings. It may be why the

```
$(this).addClass('open').text(Drupal.t('@txt',{@txt:settings.linkText}));
```

doesn't show `'@txt'` in the translation interface.