# How to make custom fieldset collapsed by default in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, 8

In Drupal 7 there was option to have fieldset collapsible or not, and to restrict default state of this form element (collapsed, or uncollapsed). Example:

```
$form['contact_data'] = array(
        '#title' => t("Contact data"),
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
```

Now, in Drupal 8 I cannot find attributtes `#collapsible` and `#collapsed` in `Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Fieldset`. In official documentation of Fieldset element is not mentioned any new element, which should substitute the Fieldset element.

Also there is not [Form API elements overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/) for Drupal 8, such as for Drupal 7. You have to manually search for all Render Elements definition in code, which is more time consuming (especially when you would like to see elements overview and compare them).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> All collapsible fieldsets have been replaced with HTML5 details
>   elements.

Fieldset and legand are very hard to style and its not recommended to use with Drupal 8 any more. Instead its replaced with more cross browser way, which is the HTML5 Details & Summary tags.

```
'#type' => 'details'
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1852020

Drupal 7

```
$form['advanced'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  '#description' => t('Lorem ipsum.'),
);
```

Drupal 8

```
$form['advanced'] = array(
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
  '#description' => t('Lorem ipsum.'),
  '#open' => TRUE, // Controls the HTML5 'open' attribute. Defaults to FALSE.
);
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer. But again, I am very frustrated from the fact, that this (not small) change is only described on some "change record" page and is not updated to official documentation pages... See:  `Online documentation: Not done`...

Comment: Change records are the perfect place to look for how thing X changed in Druapl 8. They're easily searchable and always contain before/after examples. Both code and documentation is mostly written in people's free time. Don't complain, help improve it.

Comment: @Berdir Yes, I know that documentation in written in free time and I appreciate that :) But personally I don't think, that change records are easily searchable (except from google). Primary, as developer, you search in documentation (or API documentation), so just simple link reference to specific change record would be sufficient (and it is not as time consuming as writing those examples in change records). Apart from that, I must admit, that the code examples in change records are very good.

Comment: Where do you ad this code in drupal 8 files?

Comment: How to set it to not be collapsible?

Answer (score 0):

Example using HereDoc notation to store the HTML Description:

```
$desc_html = <<<HTML
<p>
  <strong>Put the HTML to be displayed when open in here.</strong>
<p>
HTML;

$form['advanced'] = array(
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
  '#description' => t($desc_html),
  '#open' => TRUE, // Controls the HTML5 'open' attribute. Defaults to FALSE.
);
```

Comment: Variables should never be passed to `t()`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9366/8881 for an explanation.

Comment: Good catch, thanks!  Do you know if you can use a HEREDOC string in a t()?  The docs didn't specify. (at least I couldn't find it)

Comment: No I don't. But I personally wouldn't do it even if it was possible as it might confuse users who are translating strings in the UI. In the example of this answer I would only put the pure string into `t()` and then you can put that into the HereDoc string if you need to. Better even not to use markup at all, but to do the styling via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8, change the form group default closed value to open programatically -

```
function hook_field_group_form_process_build_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
      $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
      if ($node->hasField('field_pub_date') && !$node->get('field_pub_date')->isEmpty()) {
        $element['field_pub_date']['#attributes']['open'] = TRUE;
      }
}
```